# Magento 2: After enable full page cache, getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2

After turn on FPC(Full Page Cache) feature in Magento2 site, it gives "Internal Server Error 500" and site is not running.

Comment: Show your logs the error 500 got many reasons. (apache, php)

Comment: There is no error in logs. Only i can see the error in browser.

This page isn’t working

staging.saltnic.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: i mean you are in developer mod? in your index.php you are : ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;

Comment: Yes I am in developer mode. Finally I got  the error and managed to solve it.

Comment: any change recently like create new module, a copy paste of folder to your www

Comment: Dit you tryed to controls rights folder, are you in the chmod 777 ?

Comment: I removed the "freepascal" tag. Here, FPC obviously doesn't mean "FreePascal Compiler".

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the error coming from where and managed to solve it. It works for me.

By overriding the function getIdentities() in

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php

From

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    $identities = $this->getProduct()->getIdentities();
    $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
    if ($category) {
        $identities[] = Category::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $category->getId();
    }
    return $identities;
}
```

To

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    $identities = [];

    if (is_array($this->getItems()) || is_object($this->getItems()))
    {
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item)
        {
            $identities = array_merge($identities, $item->getIdentities());
        }
    }
    return $identities;
}
```